# Append multiple CSVs into one single file with Apache Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a folder with CSV files that have the same first 3 columns and different last N columns. N is minimum 2 and up to 11.

Last n columns have number as header, for example:
File 1:

```
AAA,BBB,CCC,0,10,15
1,India,c,0,28,54
2,Taiwan,c,0,23,52
3,France,c,0,26,34
4,Japan,c,0,27,46
```

File 2:

```
AAA,BBB,CCC,0,5,15,30,40
1,Brazil,c,0,20,64,71,88
2,Russia,c,0,20,62,72,81
3,Poland,c,0,21,64,78,78
4,Litva,c,0,22,66,75,78
```

Desired output:

```
AAA,BBB,CCC,0,5,10,15,30,40
1,India,c,0,null,28,54,null,null
2,Taiwan,c,0,null,23,52,null,null
3,France,c,0,null,26,34,null,null
4,Japan,c,0,null,27,46,null,null
1,Brazil,c,0,20,null,64,71,88
2,Russia,c,0,20,null,62,72,81
3,Poland,c,0,21,null,64,78,78
4,Litva,c,0,22,null,66,75,78
```

Is there a way to append this files together with Nifi where a new column would get created (even if I do not now the column name beforehad) if a file with additional data is present in the folder?

I tried with Merge content processor but by default it just appends content of all my files together without minding headers (all the headers are always appended).

Comment: What do you want if the record has duplicate values, for example:
CSV 1: 1,India,c,0,28,54
CSV 2: 2,India,c,0,20,64,71,88

Only using Nifi, I don't think this is possible.
You can write a python script to create list of lists consisting all of the columns from both the files, then add the values in the keys.

Then rewrite it to new csv file both using ExecuteScript Processor

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is write some scripts to combine the rows and columns using the ExecuteStreamCommand. This would allow you to write a custom script in whatever language you want.